# in PHP, is it possible to put function into a variable and let the string into the the variable print first?

Tags: php, function, loops

I have a question: (I've already searched it on google but i couldn't find any answer).
Is it possible that the string in the variable to run first ? 
For example :

```
   <?php

function example($times) { 
for($i = 4; $i < $times; $i++)   echo $i; 
}
$var = example(10);
echo  "3$var";

?>
```

and this code prints :

> 4567893

Comment: You need to learn Basic PHP first. What you are missing here is a return statement and the related concept.

Answer (score 3):

collect result as variable inside function and return it.

```
<?php

function example($times) { 
  $result='';
  for($i=4;$i<$times;$i++) $result.=$i; 
  return $result;
}
$var=example(10);
echo "$var"."3";
```

other way, **only in case you can't control output of function or it have many html markups**
is use output buffer capture:

```
<?php

function example($times) { 
  for($i=4;$i<$times;$i++) echo $i;
}

ob_start();
example(10);
$var=ob_get_clean;
echo "$var".3;
```

more info on [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php)

Comment: Haha, I think the rest of us were like, "buuuh for serious?" and totally missed the fact that no value was actually returned to $var. Grats. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function example($times) { 
 $str='';
 for($i = 4; $i < $times; $i++)   
  $str .=$i; 
 return $str;
}

$var = example(10);   
echo  $var."3";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the difference between `echo` and `return`.

Your function `example` will *echo* output, directly.  The value of `$var` is `NULL`, which displays nothing.

So what you are doing is actually the same as this:

```
echo 4; // in example()
echo 5; // in example()
echo 6; // in example()
echo 7; // in example()
echo 8; // in example()
echo 9; // in example()
echo "3"; // $var == '';
```

If you want to *collect* the output, write `example` like this:

```
function example($times) {
    $numberstring = '';
    for($i = 4; $i < $times; $i++) {
        $numberstring .= $i; 
    }
    return $numberstring;
}
```